# assets pipeline control coffee script's closures

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, asset-pipeline

I have 2 simple coffee scripts and assets pipeline. I obtained:

```
(function() {
  window.App.Test_widget = {...}
}).call(this);
(function() {
  $.widget("ui.Test_widget", window.App.Test_widget);
  $(document).ready(function() {...});
}).call(this);
```

but I want 1) merge closures 2) add closure parameter

```
(function($) {
  var App;
  App.Test_widget = {...}
  $.widget("ui.Test_widget", App.Test_widget);
  $(document).ready(function() {...});
})(jQuery);
```

I cant google a way of implementing this

UPD:
1) I dont want to place each file in different closures. I want to control this
2) I dont want to put anything in window if it is possible

ANSWER is simply: "use bare option. for sprockets see [commit](https://github.com/sstephenson/sprockets/commit/1f87cc9e1c0ceb25b065bd4f94387451b27b2e18)"

Comment: No, you want closures. You are having *some other specific problem* for which many solutions are possible. Please describe the problem you are actually having so you can find a good solution for *that*.

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle for what you currently have? Its really unclear to me from the description what the problem is...

Comment: puchu - I've setup a jsfiddle related to your problem. Can you MODIFY/comment on it to show what you want to do? http://jsfiddle.net/dsummersl/SeJK3/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want that level of fine-grained control over output, you'll have to write your JavaScript yourself rather than allowing CoffeeScript to do it for you. I say that as an advocate of CoffeeScript: If you use it, you have to accept certain conventions that go along with it, such as the wrapper that gives each file its own scope. You lose the freedom to concatenate files however you want in order to share variables across files.

It's worth mentioning, however, that

1. In CoffeeScript 1.2.0+, the wrapper is added only when necessary. At least in your first file, that's not the case. (**Edit:** I was mistaken about this; this feature existed in 1.1.3 but disappeared before 1.2.0)
2. Writing `$ = jQuery` at the top of a function is semantically equivalent to having an argument named `$` and passing in `jQuery` as the value of that argument. So you need only put `$ = jQuery` at the top of each of your CoffeeScript files in order to use jQuery in `noConflict` mode.

Comment: 0. I should use coffee-script 1. middleman 2.0.15.3, sprockets 2.0.3, coffee-script 2.2.0: wrapper is added always. 2. $ = jQuery in each closure is very bad

Comment: Downvoting people who are earnestly trying to help you isn't a constructive way of getting answers. You're correct that the wrapper is generated in CoffeeScript 1.2.0, though it wasn't in 1.1.3; looking into the regression now...

Comment: See https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/issues/1774#issuecomment-5383393 for explanation.

Comment: your answer was not an answer thats why I pressed minus. your last comment is an answer and I pressed plus. Do not hurry with the answer. The answer is simply: "use bare option"

Answer (score -1):

I think what you're describing is a deferred...you want to do something after your two closures finish? If so then look into [jQuery 1.5 deferred](http://www.erichynds.com/jquery/using-deferreds-in-jquery/) infrastructure.

Comment: I dont want this two closures to exist. I want to control closures but closures controls me